# Null Pointer Exception occurs while starting fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am facing this exception while starting the app on tablet. It works perfectly fine on phone.

```
> 05-06 00:34:48.213: E/AndroidRuntime(545): Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null 05-06 00:34:48.213:
> E/AndroidRuntime(545):    at
> java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method) 05-06
> 00:34:48.213: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354) 05-06
> 00:34:48.213: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491) 05-06
> 00:34:48.213: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 05-06
> 00:34:48.213: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at
> android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:562) 05-06
> 00:34:48.213: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at
> android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeaderInner(PreferenceActivity.java:1117)
> 05-06 00:34:48.213: E/AndroidRuntime(545):    at
> android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeader(PreferenceActivity.java:1150)
> 05-06 00:34:48.213: E/AndroidRuntime(545):    at
> android.preference.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:551)
```

[It looks like if the headers don't have a fragment defined, it fails on tablet as it tries to focus on the first header by default](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20231). My first header is not having a fragment, hence, the installation is failing probably. Is there a way to get around this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Adi, Am also facing same problem. Did u find any solution..?

Comment: Nope. But i did a workaround. I am showing a textview for the very first fragment which has no subscreen. The tablet tries to show a view for each fragment you have defined. For the first one, it tries to launch the child screen of the fragment and since, nothing is there it fails.